# Laravel Tree Node

Tags: laravel, tree, eloquent

[image: Json Data]

Here, I call a recursive function to get all of the user ids whose are added by a user. In this system, I work with a tree and I use JOrgChart to build my tree.

Like:

[8,16,32,33,17,34,35,9,19,36,37,.........]

## Route

```
Route::get('test11', function () {

       $jorg = new JOrgChart();
       return  $response = $jorg->testChart(2);

});
```

## JOrgChart

```
 public function testChart($referral_id)
    {

        $users = DB::table('user_referrals')
                ->where('referral_id', $referral_id)
                ->lists('user_id');

        $this->chain[$referral_id] = $users;

        //[1]=>[2 ,3]
        return $this->ecursiveTrees($users, $this->chain[$referral_id]);

    }




 public function ecursiveTrees($referral_ids, &$arr)
 {
        // [1]=>[2,3] $arr is at [1]
        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($referral_ids); $i++) {
            //index 2
               $referrals = DB::table('user_referrals')
                        ->where('referral_id', $referral_ids[$i])
                        ->lists('user_id');

              unset($arr[$i]);
              $arr[$referral_ids[$i]] = $referrals;
            if (sizeof($referrals) > 0) {
                //[2]=>[4,5] reference [2]=>
                 $this->ecursiveTrees($referrals, $arr[$referral_ids[$i]]);
            }
        }
        return $arr;
}
```

## Output

```
{
    4: {
        8: {
          16: {
              32: [ ],
              33: [ ]
              },
          17: {
              34: [ ],
              35: [ ]
              }    
       }
    }
}
```

## Expected Output

```
{ [ 
    4,
    8,
    16,
    17,
   32,
   33,
   34,
   35
]}
```

I need this output, but I can't make this output.....

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

There is no data into the image as you are expected i.e

> [2,3,5,6,67,88,8,54,43]

But if it is a JSON(as you said), then you can use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and some more array functions to do that.

Comment: I use it , but it show me an error--- json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: Can you please edit and make your question more clear so that we can help you easily?